# Joomla 2.5. prevent module from showing on article page

Tags: joomla, joomla2.5, joomla-module

I have a problem with the module that I use to show the content of a category. The module is set to show on this category, but it also shows when I open an article which is also under this same category...

What I would like is to show only article without this module and module to be visible only on category of the article.

I know this can be achieved if I add every article to a new menu which is not shown anywhere on the site but this is too much work and is complicating things to my editors. I hope this can be achieved without adding every article to a menu...

thank you!

Answer (score 3):

There is no such tool, app, plugin, or component called "Advance Menu manager"
However there is a plugin called "Advance **MODULES** manager"
And this too on Joomla 2.5 has the same issue.

I have it set to NOT show certain momdules on article, or category pages however the module still appears.

Its my impression this is because the article are inside categories which were created in a joomla version PRIOR to j 2.5

Since J2.5 no longer uses the same structure for categories, its still picking up the wrong menu ID somehow.

At this moment, i am still working this out

Comment: I am facing the same issue and am surprised this has not been fixed by Advance MODULES manager yet.

Answer (score 0):

This is due to the articles inheriting the itemID from the category. Joomla places modules based on the itemID of the menu items. In order to prevent the module(s) from displaying on the child items of a menu item, you will need to use Advance Menu manager. It has the option to only display module on the parent menu item.

Answer (score 0):

you should edit the code of the module (if it's yours) or override its view (if it's core) and start it with:

```
if (JRequest::getVar('view','')=='blog') {
```

As an alternative which I used on a fairly complex site, do this check at the template level and output two different module positions based on this, i.e. sidebar-blog and sidebar-article.

You will then have some modules duplicated (if you want them on both blog and article pages) but it's a very easy fix and requires little coding.